# Scripting Dictionary to reformat Excel table with time format

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, formatting

I started my VBA journey two months ago and I have encountered a problem which I can't solve. I have a table in a certain format which I got help to reformat using a scripting Dictionary.

I have tried to add Another variable called time and separated it by "/" Another concern that I have is that the time column is in the format "hh:mm" this can be reformated after the loop though I Believe. This is the original code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim iter As Long
Dim diter As Long
Dim countrydict As Object
Dim country As String
Dim data As String
Dim key As Variant

Set countrydict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For iter = 1 To lastrow
        country = Trim(.Cells(iter, 1).value)
        data = Trim(.Cells(iter, 2).value)
        If countrydict.Exists(country) Then
            If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0 Then 
          ' Remove  Dupes
       countrydict(country) = countrydict(country) & "|" & data 
            End If
        Else
            countrydict.Add country, data
        End If
    Next
    iter = 1
    For Each key In countrydict
        .Cells(iter, 1).value = key & ":"
        .cells(iter, 1).font.bold = True
        .cells(iter, 1).font.colorindex = 30
        iter = iter + 1
        For diter = 0 To UBound(Split(countrydict(key), "|"))
            .Cells(iter, 1).value = Split(countrydict(key), "|")(diter)
            iter = iter + 1
        Next
    Next
    .Columns("B").Clear
End With
```

This transforms my table from this format

```
 "A"   "B"
India Sales
France Sales
France Tax
Spain Sales
Spain Tax
```

Into

```
India: 
Sales
France:
Tax
Spain:
Sales
Tax
```

This works fine but I want to know how to add Another column, so if I have a table like this

```
"A"   "B"   "C"
India Sales   12:00
France Sales  09:00
France Tax    11:00
Spain Sales   11:00
Spain Tax     05:00
```

I want it to look like this

```
"A"   "B"     
India: 
Sales 12:00
France:
Sales 09:00
Tax   11:00
Spain:
Sales 11:00
Tax   05:00
```

I have tried to add

```
dim diter2 as Long
    For iter = 1 To lastrow
        country = Trim(.Cells(iter, 1).value)
        data = Trim(.Cells(iter, 2).value)
        time = Trim(.Cells(iter, 3).value)
        If countrydict.Exists(country) Then
            If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0 Then 

   countrydict(country) = countrydict(country) & "|" & data  & "/" & time
            End If
        Else
            countrydict.Add country, data, time
        End If
    Next
    iter = 1
    For Each key In countrydict
        .Cells(iter, 1).value = key & ":"
        .cells(iter, 1).font.bold = True
        .cells(iter, 1).font.colorindex = 30
        iter = iter + 1
        For diter = 0 To UBound(Split(countrydict(key), "|"))
            .Cells(iter, 1).value = Split(countrydict(key), "|")(diter)
            iter = iter + 1
           For diter2 = 0 To UBound(Split(countrydict(key), "|"))
            .Cells(iter, 2).value = Split(countrydict(key), "/")(diter2)
            iter = iter + 1    
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This should be closer to what you want.  You can either copy the time as text or as value and format the receiving cell appropriately.

```
   dim diter2 as Long, arr, arr2
    For iter = 1 To lastrow
        country = Trim(.Cells(iter, 1).value)
        data = Trim(.Cells(iter, 2).value)
        time = Trim(.Cells(iter, 3).Text) '<<<<<<
        If countrydict.Exists(country) Then
            If Not InStr(1, countrydict(country), data) > 0 Then 

                countrydict(country) = countrydict(country) & _
                                       "|" & data  & "/" & time
            End If
        Else
            countrydict.Add country, data  & "/" & time '<<<edit
        End If
    Next

    iter = 1
    For Each key In countrydict
        .Cells(iter, 1).value = key & ":"
        .cells(iter, 1).font.bold = True
        .cells(iter, 1).font.colorindex = 30
        iter = iter + 1
        arr = Split(countrydict(key), "|")
        For diter = 0 To UBound(arr)
            arr2 = Split(arr(diter), "/") 
            .Cells(iter, 1).value = arr2(0)
            .Cells(iter, 2).value = arr2(1)      
        Next diter
    Next key
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error on the countrydict.Add country, data, time line saying Run-time error '450' Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: It seems like I can't add Three variables to the Dictionary  countrydict.Add country, time works and also countrydict.Add country, time but not countrydict.Add country, data, time

Comment: Sorry I missed that issue when I posted - I was looking at the second part.  You need to concatenate data with time as you do when adding to an existing value.  See edit above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, that's what I did. :)